# Running webpack with watch enabled and starting server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle my express server, and would like to utilize the webpack watcher. I am using nodemon to restart my server when the bundle changes.

I can manually run webpack with the watcher in one terminal and start nodemon in a second, but I would, ultimately, like to be able to kick off both processes cleanly using only the "npm start" script.

ex. Webpack Bundles -> Nodemon Starts -> Webpack Watchers Start

Does anybody have any thoughts on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom build script using the Webpack/Nodemon Node APIs as opposed to the CLIs. This option provided much more flexibility for me to customize the terminal output to my liking.

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import nodemon from 'nodemon';
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.babel';

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
compiler.run((runErrors, runStats) => {
  console.log(runStats.toString({
    cached: false,
    colors: true,
    assets: true,
    chunks: false,
    chunkModules: false,
    chunkOrigins: false,
    errors: true,
    errorDetails: true,
    hash: false,
    modules: false,
    timings: false,
    warnings: false,
    version: false,
  }));
  console.log();

  nodemon({
    script: 'build/server.bundle.js',
    watch: 'build/server.bundle.js'
  }).on('restart', () => {
    process.env.NODEMON_STATUS = 'restarted';
  });

  compiler.watch({}, (watchErrors, watchStats) => {
    const hasErrors = watchErrors || watchStats.hasErrors();
    if (hasErrors) {
      console.log((watchStats.toString({
        cached: false,
        colors: true,
        assets: false,
        chunks: false,
        chunkModules: false,
        chunkOrigins: false,
        errors: true,
        errorDetails: true,
        hash: false,
        modules: false,
        timings: false,
        warnings: false,
        version: false,
        children: false,
        reasons: false,
        source: false,
      })));
    }
  });
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  process.exit(0);
});
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  process.exit(0);
});
process.on('SIGUSR2', () => {
  process.exit(0);
});
process.on('exit', () => {
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: so you run this directly on the cli or you put the call inside npm scripts package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

If nodemon automatically restart your server on file changes you can use a package called concurrently.

First install concurrently as a dev dependency.

```
npm i concurrently --save-dev
```

After that edit your package.json

```
"start": "**webpack build** && concurrently --kill-others \"nodemon app.js\" \"**webpack watch**\""
```

ps: I added ** placeholders, you should change the commands between them with your commands which builds and watches.

Comment: Is it possible to run the webpack watcher separately from the build like this? From my understanding, it is just a flag "--watch" that you append to your command.

Comment: You can run with our without watcher as you mentioned.

`"start": "**concurrently --kill-others \"nodemon app.js\" \"**webpack watch script**\""`

Comment: While this may work for some other use cases, my use case called for something a bit more custom. See my answer.